# Extracting elements from complex XML file in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following `xml` document, that need to be parsed in C# to extract below elements:

```
<Report>
  <id>820</id>
  <number>u_incident_1</number>
  <Entry>
    <findings>1</findings>
    <area>PS</area>
    <section>Section 1</section>
    <image>R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==</image>
    <image>R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==</image>
    <image>R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==</image>
  </Entry>
  <Entry>
    <findings>2</findings>
    <area>PR</area>
    <section>Section 2</section>
    <image>R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==</image>
    <image>R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==</image>
    <image>R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==</image>
  </Entry>
  <RE_image>R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==</RE_image>
  <RE_image>R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==</RE_image>
</Report>
```

(1) I would like to extract `<image>` elements (6 in total) from both entries `<Entry>` ?

(2) How to retrieve the 2 `<RE_image>` elements at the end of the document ?

Comment: There are like four or five ways to do it that I count in my head (`XmlSerializer`, `XmlDocument`, `XDocument`, `XPathNavigator` and perhaps `DataContractSerializer`), and I'm quite sure that there are tons of SO answers about how to parse XML (without even counting googling for parse xml in c#). What have you tested?

Comment: That's not what I would call complex xml. If you have trouble extracting the binary content, it looks like it's Base64 encoded.

Comment: @xanatos I spent some time googling before posting actually, but since I am new to `xml` processing, I thought of asking for help :) what I tried so far is `Linq to Xml` and `XmlDocument` but no luck in getting what I want

Comment: @PalleDue yes it is base64 encoded but that's another story, consider it as normal string and I still couldn't parse it

Comment: @khidirsanosi There is a namespace in your xml `http://test.org/test.xsd`. All the xml classes need to be "informed" of this namespace. Every one of them has a different way. Note that there are web sites that will generate serialization classes for XmlSerializer from an xml... Just googling 5 seconds gave me https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/ or https://json2csharp.com/xml-to-csharp that will even give you an example of use (for the second one check the *Add Namespace Attribute* checkbox)

Comment: @xanatos for the namespace I just changed the original one, as I thought it is company-specific info.. I removed it at the moment... I tested above websites you mentioned and it returned the class definition but not sure what to do with it ... can my problem be solved with `Linq to Xml` as I expect to be more easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can retrieve all images with XDocument library.

```
        var xmlDocument = XDocument.Load("C:\\Users\\Khora\\Desktop\\xmlDoc.xml");
        var reportElement = xmlDocument.Elements().Where(xe => xe.Name.LocalName == "Report").First();
        var allEntries = reportElement.Elements().Where(xe => xe.Name.LocalName == "Entry").ToList();
        var allImages = allEntries.SelectMany(xe => xe.Elements().Where(xe => xe.Name.LocalName == "image"));
```

Comment: thanks a lot that solved the problem at least for the first part, but I can modify it to tackle the second part as well :) PS: the second filter in the last line cannot be used twice so I had to change it to another e.g. (ze) ;)

Comment: one other thing, if I want to further filter the images, to return the images of "Section 1" only, what would be the new condition ?

Comment: @khidirsanosi Firstly retrieve first entry `XElement firstEntryXElement = allEntries.First();`

Then you can do this: `var imagesOfFirstEntry = firstEntryXElement.Elements().Where(xe => xe.Name.LocalName == "image").ToList();`

Or you can do this: `var imagesOfFirstEntry =  allImages.Where(xe => xe.Parent == firstEntryXElement).ToList();`

Comment: spendt hours to make it run but nothing :( :( how to manage the same code to get the images of <section>Section 1</section> only ?

Comment: @khidirsanosi I don't know. It works for me. My code actually obtains images from first Entry not from Entry where `<section>Section 1</section>` located. May be this is the problem? And why code is not running? What is error?